# Cannot run single test with data provider in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I've got a problem when using command line to run tests: if I run phpunit like this:

```
phpunit -–no-configuration -–filter testAdd DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

it works fine.
But we use a regular expression to specify exactly the name of the method that we want to be tested:

```
phpunit -–no-configuration -–filter /::testAdd$/ DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

The second approach is not working unfortunately.
Source code is:

```
<?php
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
          array(0, 0, 0),
          array(0, 1, 1),
          array(1, 0, 1),
          array(1, 1, 3)
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 16):

The regex to handle tests with or without data sets is

```
phpunit --filter "/::<method>( with data set .*)?$/" <class> <file>
```

For example

```
phpunit --filter "/::testAdd( with data set .*)?$/" DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

Since a test method won't have a space in the name unless it has a data set, you could really shrink this to

```
phpunit --filter "/::testAdd( .*)?$/" DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

Comment: Nice example! Note that the dataset number also might a string (named dataproviders using array keys in the datasets) so \d+ might not catch everything. But `phpunit --filter "/::test.+( with data set #.+)?$/"` or something is a very cool way to run all tests with data providers ;)

Comment: @edorian - Good call. I changed it to `.*` to catch any data set.

Comment: I think the new syntax for `--filter` is ever easier https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.examples.filter-patterns

Comment: Link to current docs: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/textui.html#textui-examples-filter-patterns

Comment: You do not have to guess or construct the test name yourself. Just run all datasets once and copy-paste (a unique substring of) the name you want from test output (and escape regexp special chars!). Example: "Test 'Drupal\Tests\migrate_drupal\Kernel\Plugin\migrate\source\ContentEntityTest::testNodeSource with data set "include_translations=1&include_revisions=1&revisions_bc_mode=1" (array(true, true, true))' started"

Answer (score 7):

Like @sjoerd pointed out the name that gets matched against contains the number of the dataset.

That means that this works:

```
phpunit --filter "testAdd with data set #0" DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

against your file produces:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.0RC1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.25Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

tested in PHPUnit 3.5 and upwards.

---

It's not really pretty and having another syntax for this within PHPUnit is definitely preferable but for now it might solve your problem and once someone sends a PR it will be nicer to use ;)

Tracking issue for the nicer syntax on the [**`phpunit github issue tracker`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/622)

Answer (score 4):

By using a data provider with named datasets it's simpler now:

```
public function provideData()
{
    yield "dataset name 1" => [
        $expected = 0,
        $val1 = 1,
        $val2 = 2
    ];

    yield "dataset name 2" => [...];
}
```

`$ phpunit --filter "dataset name 2"`

Comment: @TomášVotruba I wanned to be able to run a single test and make my tests clear but not too verbose. You can find more sample by searching "phpunit data provider yield".

Answer (score 2):

The regex in the answer no longer seems to work (at least not in 4.0.12).

It looks like --filter doesn't like the space, and gives the following error:

Fatal error: "preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset

This is fixed by replacing the space with \s  The quotes also need to get removed (or else the \ needs to be \)

```
phpunit --filter /::testAdd(\s.*)?$/ DataTest DataProviderTest.php
```

Comment: You missed the quotes around the regex to treat it as a single parameter on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the regex is matched against the following string:

```
DataTest::testAdd with data set #0
DataTest::testAdd with data set #1
...
```

So naturally your regex `testAdd$` won't work.