# how to run one specific data from a data provider in phpunit

Tags: phpunit

If I want to run a test with just one data from the data provider how would I do it?

I tried the solution on this thread and did not work
[Cannot run single test with data provider in PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193606/cannot-run-single-test-with-data-provider-in-phpunit/12198484#12198484)

Answer (score 29):

I found out that just adding `#n` would just work for numerically indexed data providers.

```
phpunit --filter ClassName::testName#datasetNumber
```

Add `@name` for associatively indexed named data providers.

```
phpunit --filter ClassName::testName@datasetName
```

Or you can use regular expressions. See the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.examples.filter-patterns) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

If data sets have names containing spaces, this works (note the `"`):

```
phpunit --filter "ClassName::testCase@data set name"
```

Answer (score 2):

If data sets have names containing spaces, not only quoting will work, you can also use "\ " (at least in a shell like sh or bash)

```
phpunit --filter ClassName::testCase@data\ set\ name
```

Comment: I use ConEmu and classic cmd on Win and I need to add `"` around: `"ClassName::testCase@data set name"`, I don't need to use backslash before spaces

Comment: That's why my answer was in addition of your answer

Comment: Note that  the name of the provider NEEDS to be exactly like its definition, but the name of the method may contain partial text. `"testCase@data set na"` would not work, but `"stCase@data set name"` would